# Xcode : The file “XXX.entitlements” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, xcode

Cause my old machine was damaged so I copied the project to another machine and build&run it but xcode return error :

> warning: Falling back to contents of entitlements file
>   "XXX.entitlements" because it was modified during the build
>   process. Modifying the entitlements file during the build is
>   unsupported.error: The file “XXX.entitlements” couldn’t be opened
>   because there is no such file.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Well, *is* there an entitlements file?

Answer (score 114):

Go to your build settings and empty the Entitlements value. 
[image]

Hope this work for you

Comment: Works for me, thought it's kind of odd!

Answer (score 8):

I hit the same error.  When build, Xcode could not find the .entitlements file.  The root cause: I caused the error by renaming a folder inside my xCode project.

[image]

The fix was to remove the hardcoded path (that Xcode had used).

Answer (score -3):

Is it looking for an Entitlements.plist file?

Maybe delete bin and obj folders and try to rebuild? I'm not too familiar with XCode but this is what I would do on Xamarin iOS.